# Integration over the surface of a torus

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\boldsymbol{r}(\theta,\psi)=[(2+\cos(\theta))\cos(\psi), (2+\cos(\theta))\sin(\psi), \sin(\theta)]$$
For:
$$S = \lbrace\boldsymbol{r}(\theta,\psi)|\theta,\psi\in[0,2\pi]\rbrace$$

Evaluate:

$$\iint_S\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dA$$

Comment: @CliveNewstead nothing with confidence, I'm unsure of how to deal with the element of surface area, reading up at the moment. I am in particular looking for any nice tricks/short-cuts, stuff that I might otherwise miss.

Comment: @TedShifrin is the typo to do with the cos, because I can't see another. I'm glad you said that, I was thinking "but x^2-y^2 will be zero ... quite a lot" it is actually a very faded +, no wonder I was particularly confused, I also tried "just going for it" and got something in the integrand to do with $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos(2\psi)}}$ which I know to have no analytic solution, I removed it because of embarrassment, assuming I'd gone wrong. PS: in my defense the + is VERY faded...

Comment: OK. Now that the problem is corrected, the integral should end up very, very easy once you use the standard formula for $dA$.

Comment: @TedShifrin corrected, very sorry about the errors in the question.

Comment: @TedShifrin are you referring to the one that involves the cross product (used as the area of a parallelogram) I promise you I can do that! I was looking for short cuts and tricks to get there quicker (I've noticed that reading answers to other questions is actually quite informative, so I've started asking questions about things I can do in the hope of finding a faster/better way) - it is a very "simple" surface, and the 1/radius integrand is also VERY nice, I do think there's a short cut here.

Comment: I assume you are in a standard multivariable calculus class and don't know differential forms or differential geometry. You can do the cross product in two minutes. Perhaps once you do, you'll see an intuitive (physicists') geometric argument. Can you see that for the standard sphere and cylinder parametrizations?

Comment: @TedShifrin no, I do know forms and have studied differential geometry, I really was just short-cut-hunting, and yes I get geometric argument. I was stuck but as you pointed out the question was wrong.

Comment: With forms, you see that an orthonormal basis for the $1$-forms is $\omega_1=(2+\cos\theta)d\psi$ and $\omega_2=d\theta$, which, of course, corresponds to the intuitive approach I suggested earlier. Then $dA=\omega_1\wedge\omega_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Up to [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area) the integral under consideration can be written as a double integral in such way: $$J:=\iint_S\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\,dA=\iint_S\frac{1}{\sqrt{((2+\cos(\theta))\cos(\psi))^2+((2+\cos(\theta))\sin(\psi))^2}}dA=$$ $$\iint_{\theta \in [0,2\pi],\\ \psi \in [0,2\pi]}\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2+\cos(\theta))^2}}\sqrt{\left(\frac {\partial(x,y)}{\partial(\theta,\psi)}\right)^2+\left(\frac {\partial(y,z)}{\partial(\theta,\psi)}\right)^2+\left(\frac {\partial(z,x)}{\partial(\theta,\psi)}\right)^2}\,d\psi\,d\theta. $$ Next, $$ \left(\frac {\partial(x,y)}{\partial(\theta,\psi)}\right)^2+\left(\frac {\partial(y,z)}{\partial(\theta,\psi)}\right)^2+\left(\frac {\partial(z,x)}{\partial(\theta,\psi)}\right)^2=$$ $$\left( -  \sin( \psi ) ^2\sin(
\theta ) \cos ( \theta ) -\sin ( \theta )
  \cos ( \psi ) ^2\cos ( \theta
 ) -2\,  \sin ( \psi )  ^2\sin
 ( \theta ) -2\,\sin ( \theta ) \cos
 ( \psi )  ^2 \right) ^2+
 $$
 $$(-(2+\cos(\theta))\cos(\psi)\cos(\theta))^2+(-\cos(\theta)(2+\cos(\theta))\sin(\psi))^2=$$ $$ \cos ( \theta )   ^2+4\,\cos \left( \theta
 \right) +4=(2+\cos(\theta))^2.
 $$ Thus, we have the happy end $$J= \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi}1\,d\psi\,d\theta=4\pi^2.$$

Comment: Could you explain how you got from the first to the second line? I did it using $\lvert\frac{\partial{\boldsymbol{r}}}{\partial{\theta}}\times \frac{\partial{\boldsymbol{r}}}{\partial{\psi}}\rvert d\theta\ d\psi$

Comment: @ Alec Teal: I did the same thing.

Comment: What to the partials denote? Jacobian matrix I thought?

Comment: You are right.  The notatons $$\det\left(\frac {\partial(x,y)}{\partial(\theta,\psi)}\right),\dots $$ or $$ \left|\frac {\partial(x,y)}{\partial(\theta,\psi)}\right|,\dots $$ are more exact.